# Redirection not working in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect

I am using below code for redirection in wordpress

```
$currentPage = explode('?', $_SERVER ['REQUEST_URI']);
  $current_page_url = $currentPage[0];
 if($current_page_url == '/e-commerce')
    {
        header("Location : http://www.mysite.com/complete-e-commerce-solution",true);
    }
```

I am using this code in header.php, i am redirecting to third party site.is that problem?

Comment: what exactly is the error or result you are receiving?

Comment: What is the value of `$currentPage`

Comment: @Ross i got a value for $currentPage as /e-commerce only. but the redirection not happened

Comment: I meant the value of `$current_page_url`, my mistake. So if you do a `print_r($currentPage); exit;` what output do you get? And I assume this is before any other output?

Comment: why are you using php for this ? would `htaccess` not suffice ?

Comment: i got an another idea..i used redirection plugin for redirection.now its working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to follow the header call with an 'exit`. However, you might be better using wordpress's inbuilt [wp_redirect](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_redirect) function:

```
wp_redirect("Location : http://www.mysite.com/complete-e-commerce-solution");
exit;
```

Using wordpress functions allows plugins to filter the input and sanitises the input (not so applicable here, just good practice).

Comment: Are you using exit or die immediately afterwards? This is necessary to ensure that only the headers are getting sent.

Answer (score 0):

Any chance of getting `/e-commerce` from `$currentPage[0]`? The `'/e-commerce'` looks more like something that would be found at `$currentPage[1]`.