# How can i redirect index.php to other link in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

My index page is `http://www.cyrusengineer.com/` I want to redirect this to `http://www.cyrusengineer.com/home`

Is there any method in .htaccess

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redirection not working in Wordpress?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6236607/redirection-not-working-in-wordpress)

Answer (score 2):

Redirect index.html to a specific path from .htaccess:

This allows you to redirect index.html to a specific subfolder

```
Redirect /index.html http://www.cyrusengineer.com/home
```